# SSIS increment for loop counter resets to 1 after 99

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package which contains a for loop container and I have two variables `@counter` and `@counterlimit`.

I have assigned:

- `1` to `@counter`
- `180` to `@counterlimit`.
- Eval expression = `@counter<=@counterlimit`

The loop works well until 99 after which the `@counter` value is reset to 1 and then loop completes at 180.

Do you why that might be?

Comment: Probably nothing to do with it, but what datatypes are the variables? How are you observing the value of the counter?

Comment: @JSG can you attach a screenshot of the for-loop configuration dialog?

Comment: The data types are int32

Comment: _value is reset to 1 and then loop completes at 180_ if it is always reset to 1 how does it get to 180?? How are you observing the variable value? With a msgbox? Be aware that when you stop your package, the variable values are reset so this is not a reliable way to observe the value

Comment: I am inserting all 180 values into a table and then when I view the table - it shows that counter values as 1s after 99

Comment: There is definitely room for misinterpretation here. Before you assume the issue is in the package, please use this technique to inspect the variable and confirm whether it's doing what you think it's doing http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop

Comment: You must have a step that writes the variable to a table - that could be incorrect. Also keep in mind there is no "after" in a table. There's no guarantee those records are coming back in the order they were inserted. Lastly just keep in mind that you can probably do whatever you're doing in pure T-SQL and that takes away all the complication of passing variables in and out of databases.